# What is the "::" equivalent function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda

In Python, we have a built-in package, named "operator", with which we can use function version of any operator. It is highly used when using "functional Programming" functions like map and reduce, and is much better recommended than using "lambda".

I have the same problem in Haskell: I want t user mapM somewhere with a composition of many functions but I have to use not-so-pretty lambda:

```
mapM ((\x->x::String).fromSql.(!!1)) res
```

Is there any equivalent to that liek this:

```
mapM (someFunc(String).fromSql.(!!1)) res
```

Comment: It's possible to do "id @String" in GHC 8.0: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication

Comment: `mapM (asTypeOf "".fromSql.(!!1)) res` -- unless you have `XOverloadedStrings` on.

Comment: Are you sure `mapM (fromSql.(!!1)) res` isn't sufficient, or `mapM ((fromSql.(!!1)) :: a -> String) res`?

Answer (score 1):

`::String` is not an operator in the sense of python’s `string(…)`, but a type annotation, and as such, special syntactic rules apply.

You can, however, define function

```
asString :: String -> String
asString x = x
```

and then write

```
mapM (asString.fromSql.(!!1)) res
```

@augustss once [proposed a language extension](http://augustss.blogspot.de/2014/04/a-small-haskell-extension.html) that would allow `(::String)` to be used, but I cannot find it right now.)

Comment: !!1 does not mean head, since it gets the second element not the first.
I don't mean identity, I just want a type hint to stop getting ambiguous type error.

Comment: Yes I got the point: if we have a identity function with concrete type, we can use it like a type hint. But is there any other way except defining it again?

Comment: This seems like much too much work to simply give a type annotation.. the type of the expression `mapM ... res` can itself be specified and from this type inference is likely to find the correct type for `fromSql`. Alternatively one can write `fromSQL :: _ -> String` (with -XPartialTypeSignatures)

Comment: Removed my off-by-one mistake about `!!1`.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner commented, it really shouldn't be necessary to give any type hint at all: all you need is

```
   mapM (fromSql . (!!1)) res
```

...that is, provided you actually *use* the result in some way. (If you don't use the result, then why do you do this in the first place?)

The reason being: unlike Python, Haskell has a proper Hindley-Milner type system, and this can infer types in any direction<sup>†</sup> and any context. So if you write just, for instance,

```
 do
   sqlStrs <- mapM (fromSql . (!!1)) res
   ...
   mapM_ putStrLn sqlStr
```

then this is enough for the compiler to infer that `sqlStrs :: [String]` and hence `fromSql` must be restricted to yield `String`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>There are some exceptions, but these arise only with the monomorphism restriction (which only applies to global definitions, not to something bound in a monad, and can also be turned off) or when using extensions like GADTs, ExistentialQuantification or RankNTypes.</sub>